# No data recover from incluster config with kubernetes/go-client

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-go-client

I made a demo with kubernetes/go-client where i tried to list pods from my cluster.

```
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})

    fmt.Fprint(w, "There are d pods in the cluster\n", len(pods.Items))
```

I created serviceaccount token to assign to the pod where this code is running in.

But when code is executed pods.Items has no pods.

I deployed this pod inside minikube. When I launch some kubectl command for listing pods, this way I can get resources so it is no t permissions problems.

I wonder what is happening and how i can fix it.

---

Repository https://github.com/srpepperoni/inframanager.git

Image is pushed into: https://hub.docker.com/r/jaimeyh/inframanager

The endpoint I have problems with is this one :

```
mux.HandleFunc("/getPods", GetPodsFromNamespace)
```

Comment: Is your last `err` non-nil? or does it contain a message?

Comment: When I run this code on my minikube, this show the next message. Theresa are 0 podes in the clúster.

Comment: Is your last `err` non-nil?

Comment: No, last err from 
```
clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
```
is nill

Comment: Yeah, but you need to check the `err` from when you are Listing the Pods

Comment: OK, there is the problem. 
pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:mis-pruebas:sa-prueba-go" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope

So, the way I created the service account is not the correct isn't it?

Comment: The ServiceAccount is correct, but it does not have permission to list the pods. So you need to assign permission to the ServiceAccount using Role RBAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the `err` on the last line is non-nil.

```
pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
```

> OK, there is the problem. pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:mis-pruebas:sa-prueba-go" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope

As the error message indicates, the ServiceAccount does not have permission to list pods at cluster scope. You need to create Role and bind it to the ServiceAccount.

The article [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) even has a [role example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-example) for how to create such a role.

Comment: thx, now I know why I cant list pods. Now I will try to figure out how to give permissions to service-account-token, cuz seems that it is not working same way that normal service accounts.